# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@id' to data type int

Tags: stored-procedures, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I have 3 textboxes and add button. When the button is clicked it should in insert info from textboxes to the database. The problem is when it is clicked i have the following error: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@id' to data type int.`
Here is add button onclick event:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source="Name";Initial Catalog="Name";Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("addData", conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFName.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLName.Text;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataSource = rd;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Also i have a stored procedure which adds data and i think i might made a mistake here:

```
USE ['Name']
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[addData]
@id int,
@FName varchar(30),
@LName varchar(30)
as
begin
Insert into Customer(ID, FName, LName)
Values('@id', '@FName', '@LName')
end
```

Please help me to find my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to replace

```
Values('@id', '@FName', '@LName')
```

with

```
Values(@id, @FName, @LName)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `@` sign in you parameters.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source="Name";Initial Catalog="Name";Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("addData", conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int)
                          .Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FName",System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
                          .Value = txtFName.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
                          .Value = txtLName.Text;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataSource = rd;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            conn.Close()//don't forget to close conn
```